# (Qt) Validate string against multiple regular expressions simultaneously

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm checking a string which contains vehicle registration information against regular expressions for validity. I have several regular expression for each criteria I need. How can I validate the string against all my reg expressions without having to combine them into one expression or do something like this to determine if it's valid?

```
if( s_expGP.exactMatch(lineEdit->text()) ||
    s_expGPNew.exactMatch(lineEdit->text()) ||
    s_expPersonal.exactMatch(lineEdit->text()) ||
    s_expGov.exactMatch(lineEdit->text()) )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without combining the expressions into one. The straightforward way to simultaneously match multiple expressions is to combine them with `|` (and if you need to know which one had a match, you can put each expression into its own named capture group). There could be hope that you could apply logical 'or' to the objects representing compiled expressions; but although it makes sense to have this operation, I don't know of any library that allows to do it.

Comment: It is impossible. Probably you wanted to know if it can be done using one regex expression, then, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only option would be to create a single regular expression by combining s_expGP, s_expGPNew, s_expPersonal and the rest if that is possible, otherwise I don't think there could be any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big number of regexp to test or if you may need to verify the string more than once. You can create a function like this

```
bool isValid(const QVector<QRegExp>& regExps, const QString& input)
{
    for(QRegExp exp : regExps)
    {
        if(!exp.exactMatch(input))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or use a static QVector like you have static regexp.